# Expect spawn id not open

Tags: linux, shell, unix, redhat, expect

In a short note, I work on a tool which kicks of backup scripts written in the shell which in turn uses EXPECT to connect to remote servers and execute the shell script.

I get below error for either a long-running expect-jobs or when multiple jobs are being kicked off with different values of arguments.

```
expect: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"expect "*>" { send  "exit\r" }"
    (file "/oraadmin/ettool/upgradescripts/expct_orig_scripts/expdp_expct.sh" line 25)
```

Though the script is coming out from the machine I execute, it still runs on the remote server.

Here is the code:

```
set SoDb [lrange $argv 4 4]
set SoCl [lrange $argv 5 5]
set x  [lrange $argv 6 6]
set THEDATE [lrange $argv 7 7 ]
set timeout -1
#echo $scn_source
spawn ssh -q [lindex $argv 1]@[lindex $argv 0]
log_user 0
expect "yes/no" {
        send "yes\r"
        expect -re "(.*)assword:"  { sleep 5; send "[lindex $argv 2]\r" }
        } -re "(.*)assword:"  { sleep 5; send "[lindex $argv 2]\r" }
expect "*>" { send "sudo su - [lindex $argv 3]\r" }
sleep 5
expect -re "(.*)assword:" {
         sleep 5;send "[lindex $argv 2]\r"
        expect "*]" { send " /orashare/ettool/expdp.sh ${SoDb} ${SoCl} $x $THEDATE\r" }
        } "*]" {  send " /orashare/ettool/expdp.sh ${SoDb} ${SoCl} $x $THEDATE\r" }
log_user 1
expect "*]" { send  "exit\r" }
expect "*>" { send  "exit\r" }
expect eof
```

I couldn't find an exact situation in any of the stack overflow threads, please do assist.

Comment: Add `exp_internal 1` before `log_user 1`. This will give you debug output

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have debugged it.

Debuged output for the error is:

expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""
expect: spawn id exp6 not open